# How to set UIScrollView content size for AutoLayout enabled UIVIew

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout, ipod, ipod-touch

I'm using Autolayout feature in one of my UIView, As per the documentation I have not created separate xib for iPad and iPod, I have created one xib for iPad and trying to use the same for iPod also with AutoLayout feature, everything works fine however the scroll view I'm using has content size same like iPad, so Its scrolling long down, I have attached image for reference please check this and let me know what to do for this case.
[image]

Note: Problem here is size of view which I'm unable to resize for AutoLayout.

Thanx for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

set contensize :

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
    {
       // set your  requirement size
        [yourscrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
    }
    else
    {
      // set your  requirement size
       [yourscrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1100)];
    }
```

Comment: I have tried, its not working. I guess, problem is here view size is more, so content size setting not taking into account. As I am using Autolayout, setFrame also won't work for UIView.